# How many shards for elastic search with two servers?

Tags: search, indexing, sharding, elasticsearch

If i run elastic search with two servers - How many shards should be defined for an index?

Regards
Rafael

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking the wrong question.

A `shard` means in "how many parts" a single index on a single machine is split. It's primarily a factor for scaling the data, not necessarily the servers.

I think what you want to know if your [`number_of_replicas`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/indices-update-settings.html) is sufficient enough? Replicas are the "additional copies" in addition to the primary shard.

The index defaults are 5 shards and 1 replica, which means:

1. your index gets split into 5 shards in every machine it is
2. it gets copied to at most 1 other machine

At least 2) is the right preset for your two-server scenario.

Whether 1) (number of shards) is sufficient, probably depends on the amount of data you have. But if you just started out, even with two servers, it's a sensible default which should work well (I put a lot of assumptions in the last sentence, so YMMV).

Another important thing:

- you **cannot** change the shards on the index, once created; however
- you **can** change the `number_of_replicas` anytime!